# How Many Save Files Can You Have In Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

I need to know if you can have multiple save files for tomodachi life (3ds).

Answer (score 2):

Tomodachi Life only has one save file. So no, you cannot have multiple save files on one copy.

Comment: Just to notice, save data is saved on the game cartridge. So the only way to have multiple save files is by buying multiple copies and switching the cartridge.